# WPF ListView Items Rendered Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I'm using a **WPF ListView**, and I bind the **ItemsSource** property to different collections, based on the user's choice.
When the app changes or replaces the collection that is bound to the **ItemsSource** property then the new list items are rendered on the screen.

Is there any way I can **detect when the rendering is complete**? What kind of event do I need to subscribe to?

So far I have tried:

- **Loaded event**: only called the first time, not after the bound collection is changed or replaced
- **OnChildDesiredSizeChanged method**: not always gets called when the bound collection changes
- **LayoutUpdated event**: not always gets called when the bound collection changes

Comment: One thing that saved many seconds of the UI's locking was keeping ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True". This enables virtualization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score -1):

You can acheive this by writing an async method with await in it where we give our item source so only after the completion we move further.

```
public async void A()
{
   await Task.Run(new Action(B))
}

public void B()
{
   //Give source for listvView here
}
```

by this way we you can move further only when the list view is completely loaded with the source data

Comment: Could you show me a code sample for this? What exactly do I have to await?